# Minted styling not working : no pygstyle file created

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting, pygments

> I want to start this post by telling that I already know the answer to the question. I just came here to post the solution I found so it hopefully helps someone without having to spend an hour understanding what is going on like I did by searching on Google and finding this post.

## The problem

I want to document the custom commands I made, so I want syntax highlight using minted inside tabular environments :

```latex
\prodscal x y
```

However the render gives :

[image: minted is not working]

there is not even the beginning `\`, and obviously no syntax highlight.

this is the code used :

```latex
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
        \textbf{Command}                     & \textbf{location}                                               & \textbf{short desc.}                            & \textbf{Example}               \\
        \midrule
        % ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
        \mintinline{latex}{\indicatrice}     & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & indicatrice d'un ensemble                       & $\indicatrice{A}$              \\ \\

        \mintinline{latex}{\norme}           & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & norme d'un élément                              & $\norme{p}{x}$                 \\ \\

        \mintinline{latex}{\dist}            & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & distance issue d'une norme entre deux vecteurs  & $\dist{x}{y}$                  \\ \\

        \mintinline{latex}{\distnorme}       & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & distance issue d'une norme entre deux vecteurs  & $\distnorme{\infty}{x}{y}$     \\ \\

        \mintinline{latex}{\prodscal}        & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & produit scalaire entre deux vecteurs            & $\prodscal{x}{y}$              \\ \\

        \mintinline{latex}{\prodscalselon}   & \detokenize{fonctions_et_}\linebreak\detokenize{operateurs.tex} & produit scalaire [spécifié] entre deux vecteurs & $\prodscalselon{x}{y}{\infty}$ \\ \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

```
! Package catchfile Error: File `../aux_files/_minted-documentation/one-dark.pygstyle' not found.

! Package minted Error: Cannot find Pygments style one-dark.

Cannot find Pygments style one-dark

! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,or may be using frozencache with a missing file.
```

## what I have already looked for

I use latexmk to put my aux files somewhere else :

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode';
# PROJECT CODE FILES
$do_cd= 1;
$cd_dir="src";
@default_files = ('src/rapport.tex', 'src/documentation.tex', 'src/tests.tex');

# ~ OUTPUT FILES

$pdf_mode=1; # use pdflatex

$out_dir = "../out";

# ~ AUXILIARY FILES

$emulate_aux = 1;

$aux_dir = "../aux_files";
```

and I was already dealing with that when I import the package

```latex
\usepackage[cache=true, outputdir={\detokenize{../aux_files}} ]{minted}

\usemintedstyle{one-dark}
```

Moreover, another file within the project also using minted compiles just fine with the style.

I noticed that `one-dark.pygstyle` is created in the aux folder for that .tex file but the one where I have problems. Why is it not created ? what should I do so it can be created properly ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two files was :

- The working one : has minted environments as well as minted inlines
- the not working one : only has minted inlines

Therefore one must need to call at least one minted environment to trigger the style generation. However I don't want to use an environment in my doc, the solution I sugggest is :

```latex
\begin{document}
    \begin{phantom}
        \begin{minted}{latex}
        \end{minted}
    \end{phantom}

    ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can't be the answer, but your question is not clear enough to have an example that reproduces the problem. Note like all verbatim environments `\mintinline` can not be used in the arguments of other commands, or in environments like `tabularx` that grab the environment body as a macro.

Comment: Hi, the steps I described did effectively solve the problem I had which is not having style highlighting in the mintedinline environments. I am no expert of LaTeX though and my workaround might be a weird trick that works for the wrong reasons. But I made that post to hopefully help others, so, how should I modify the post to have a clearer reproducible example ? Should I provide a complete document ( imports, document environment, ... ) ? I have a LOT of imports and custom definitions but I could maybe trim some.

Comment: I suspect that you misread what you saw,  if this works you should be able to edit so instead of a `...` fragment that can not be used, have a small complete document with a mintedinline that does not work, and then a second document that has the same but preceded by a `minted` block that makes the following inline work.

Comment: > "Note like all verbatim environments \mintinline can not be used in the arguments of other commands, or in environments like tabularx that grab the environment body as a macro."


I am interested in the meaning of that sentence if you have an explanation of how that works. However the mintedinline environment did get parsed as expected inside tabularx in the end : therefore I am pretty confused by that sentence

Thanks for the answer @DavidCarlisle 

- Instable.

Comment: if your code block does not use special latex characters such as `\ ` or `&` then it may "almost work" but normally minted makes these "safe" like a standard `\verb`  but that will not happen in tabularx or a macro argument, as the whole string has already been tokenised before minted is called.  This is like in standard latex with no packages  you can use `\verb|foo|` anywhere but it is just `\texttt{foo]`  but if you try `\verb|\foo|` in a macro argument you will get anundefined `\foo` error. `tabularx` makes `\verb` safe with some conditions, but it does nothing for minted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle alright, I will provide a fully detailed document that can be rendered : both for the document with the problem and the one which "has the problem solved"
I will join the compile logs as well ( not fully though, otherwise the post will be 7 pages long ) so that it might be clearer for everyone